# CSS display absolute behind fake device frame

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions

So, I am emulating a pin screen in a device frame. [See CodeSandbox here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-microservice-795xw?file=/src/App.js) I'd like for this pin screen to transition upwards and disappear, the problem is that for now, it only goes up, but does not go behind the device frame.

I could solve this by making the pin screen go all the way up to the screen edge, but the animation would still be broken when sliding up. Is there any other way to achieve something similar?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the screen is transitioning its top - to -100%. It is actually in front of the 'device' - which it needs to be to cover the device's screen - but it needs to look as though it is contained by the device's screen.

One way is to stop transitioning the top position - leave it where it is which is the top of the device's screen - and transition instead its height down to 0. That way we don't have to worry about whether it is showing behind the device (especially difficult to achieve as the device has rounded corners).